# restricting paint event handler

Tags: c#, events, user-controls, handler, paint

I have a scroll bar user control with a paint handler, and I was wondering if there is a way to restrict the location where a user can draw on my scroll bar. For example I would only wont them to draw on the thumb scroll background and nowhere else.

My current code is something like this.

```
public event PaintEventHandler paintEvent = null;
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{          
      //---------------other code------------------  
    if (this.paintEvent != null)
        this.paintEvent(this, new PaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(1, UpArrowImage.Height, this.Width - 2, (this.Height - DownArrowImage.Height - UpArrowImage.Height))));   
     //----------------other code------------------
}
```

Where the Rectangle is the location in which I would like to allow users to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Graphics.SetClip(clipRectangle)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4b8da49%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method before you raise `paintEvent` and call [ResetClip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.resetclip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after it. If you need a non rectangular area as a clip you can use [Graphics.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Your code becomes:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var tempEvent = this.paintEvent;//To avoid race
    if (tempEvent != null)
    {
        e.Graphics.SetClip(clipRectangle);
        try
        {
            tempEvent(this, new PaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(1, UpArrowImage.Height, this.Width - 2, (this.Height - DownArrowImage.Height - UpArrowImage.Height))));   
        }
        finally
        {
            e.Graphics.ResetClip();
        }
    }    
}
```

By this way if user draws beyond the clipRectangle specified, it will be clipped and not drawn.

Nevertheless, If user is clever he can call `ResetClip` by his own. So you're at risk.

Comment: Is there a way to make a new graphics with that restriction and pass that. then afterwords change the original. hence it will not be changed back with ResetClip().

Comment: @user3813249 Nope, no way. You can write a wrapper class over `Graphics` which doesn't expose `SetClip` method or `Clip` property. but that's not worth the effort. User can still use reflection to change it. My suggestion is call `SetClip` and forget it.